# Parse.com: How to Generate Facebook User Access Token from Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication, parse-cloud-code

I'm a novice developer and use Parse.com to power the backend of my iPhone app.

I was wondering if it was possible to manage Facebook OAuth issues from Parse's cloud code (my backend) using http requests or the Facebook JS SDK.

For example: a user's long-term access token becomes invalidated due to expiration. I would like to be able to generate a new access token on the backend, given that I have access to: the old access token, my app_id, my app_secret, and the user's facebookID.

Q1: is it possible to generate a user access token using an http request? I know that I can generate an app access token, but this is not what I want (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). If it is possible, what is the correct structure for the http request (I've spent several hours trying to find an example and haven't been able to).

Q2: if #1 is not possible, is it possible to use the Facebook JS SDK in Parse Cloud code? Parse has previously stated this is not supported since the Facebook JS SDK assumes/necessitates being executed from a browser, but wouldn't it be possible to mimic a browser and still have this function correctly? If so, please provide example code.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this question has been answered already here: https://parse.com/questions/cloud-code-how-to-get-current-users-facebook-access-token

`Parse.User.current().get('authData')['facebook']`